# If the fields $F_\alpha^0$ are independent, then so are the B.F.'s $F_\alpha$.

Tags: probability-theory

Problem 4 of Section 3.3 from "A Course in Probability Theory" by Kai Lai Chung

Fields or B.F.'s $F_\alpha(\subset F)$ of any family are said to be independent iff any collection of events, one from each $F_\alpha$, forms a set of independent events. Let $F_\alpha^0$ be a field generating $F_\alpha$. Prove that if the fields $F_\alpha^0$ are independent, then so are the B.F.'s $F_\alpha$. Is the same conclusion true if the fields are replaced by arbitrary generating sets? Prove, however, that the conditions (1) and (2) are equivalent.

I have no clue what it means in the last sentence. But ignoring that, how is the result even possible? Consider even the simplest example that doesn't even involve countably infinitely many sets. For example $A,B\subset F_\alpha^0$ and $C\subset F_\beta^0$, then $A\cup B$ and $C$ are suppose to be independent. How is that possible given that $A$ and $C$ are independent and $B$ and $C$ are independent but $A$ and $B$ need not be independent?

Comment: You might start by looking for some conditions (1) and (2) somewhere in the text of your homework.

Comment: Now that you indicated the book, this is clear: (1) and (2) in the definition at the beginning of section 3.3, obviously!

Comment: @Did: but ignoring those (1) and (2) what about the rest of the problem.

Comment: Please include (1) and (2) in your post.